# second AsyncResult in Celery returns None[Python]

Tags: python, celery

When I create the second AsyncResult, I get nothing when I try to get the task result (the PENDING status). How can this be avoided?

```
        res = AsyncResult(task_id)
        print(task_id)
        result = res.get()
        print(result)
        res = AsyncResult(task_id)
        result = res.get()
        print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cache the result if you may need it again. Calling `get()` and `forget()` frees resources created to store that AsyncResult object data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there no way for celery to get around this deletion of results? In the config, celery saw something related to the cache.